# JSON do something if data exists and do something else if it doesn't

Tags: python, json, sorting

I have an API of JSON data that has ~600 entries that each contain changing data about an object. In some cases, there is a key data value and in others, there isn't. I want to check to see if that JSON data is present and store it and if it's not moved on to the next device.

Trying to sort out entries that have specific data and those that don't:

```
if data["entity"][n]["sensor_data"]["light_ intensity"] in data["entity"]:
    logger.debug("There is light_intensity data on this devcie")
    light_ intensity = data["entity"][n]["sensor_data"]["light_ intensity"]
```

What is the best way to do this? Right now I'm getting a `KeyError` that 'light_ intensity' is not defined - If I manually look at the data and search for an entity that does have `light_ intensity` data and hardcode it like this.

```
light_ intensity = data["entity"][222]["sensor_data"]["light_intesity"]
logger.debug("Devcie 222 light_intesity: %s lums", light_intesity)
```

Returns:

```
Device 222 light_intensity: 88 lums
```

This tells me that I can read data from entity's that do have the data buy get a `KeyError` from those that don't. I'm trying to create a search in a sense that allows me to find what devices have light readings percent and use that data and skip devices that are not currently sending that data.

Comment: Can you show an example when `data["entity"][n]["sensor_data"]["light_intesity"] in data["entity"]` will be true?

Comment: `if "light_intesity" in data["entity"][n]["sensor_data"]: # key is present `

Comment: To really be able help you we need to see a sample of the JSON data being parsed (with and without the data in question).  Please [edit] your question and add that information. Also the problem may have something to do with your misspelling `"light_intesity"` (seems like it should be `"light_intensity"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> KeyError that 'light_intesity'is not defined

First of all, you spelled **intensity** wrong, and the value of `light_intensity` won't be `in data["entity"]` if that is a list of dicts, but the intensity is only a number.

But if you want to loop over all elements and are not sure if they are there, use `dict.get(key, default)`.

```
for i, e in enumerate(data.get("entity", [])):
    sensor_data = e.get("sensor_data", dict())
    light_intensity = sensor_data.get("light_intensity", None)
    logger.debug("Device %d ; light_intensity: %s lums", i, light_intensity)
```

Comment: I like how you used another dict as the return val ```e.get("sensor_data", dict())``` so you didn't have to do any error checking. Never though about doing that.

Comment: Thank you and my mistake for the spelling mistake, I fix it in the question. I looked up the `dict.get(key, default)` and it definitely solves my problem, python has so many pre-built functions.